# Jquery UI Datepicker not working with bootstrap and Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

I have a jquery ui datepicker with changeMonth and changeYear set to True in a bootstrap modal. On the modal div I have an attribute "tabindex='-1'". This works fine in Chrome, IE.. but not in Firefox. If i remove the tabindex, it works in FF. I would like to keep the tabindex attribute if possible, any idea ?

edit :
I know tabindex it's not for div but this is on the twitter bootstrap documentation.

Comment: Can you provide a demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LeH4Q/4/

Answer (score 7):

A solution, append the ui-datepicker-div to the modal.

```
$('#ui-datepicker-div').appendTo($('#modal'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LeH4Q/5/

Comment: This works well, provided you only have the one datepicker. If you have one inside a modal and another outside the modal on a single page, only the modal one will work.